# Discrepancies in unique opens v's unique clicks if SFMC data

Tags: marketing-cloud

I recently send an email to 120 customers. This is the returned open and click data.

```
Total delivered = 120
Opens = 102 Unique opens = 46
Did not open = 74
Clicks = 202 Unique clicks = 94
Did not click = 26
```

When I drill down and  look at the data for each individual I see there are customers who 'did not open' but in the 'unique open' data they are showing as having clicked on a link. I'm not sure why SFMC is not recording them as unique opens.

Can anyone help me understand what's going on.

Many thanks.

Miles

Answer (score 4):

Opens are gathered by a tracking pixel (image) so if images are blocked or off (or otherwise manipulated/obscured) then it will not be recorded as an open.

So in that vein if you send B2B emails to say a company that uses a restricted Outlook client, you could have 0 recorded opens and 100 clicks because of the image blocking. This is why it is usually not a good idea to put much reliance or importance to the open metric - especially now with the Apple mail updates.